# RDMBS to Cassandra - Did current user liked queryed post?

Tags: database-design, cassandra, nosql, cql

I'm am trying to workout how to create model in Cassandra so that I get information in some efficient way (possible single query) whether the currently logged in user liked post along with post data. In RDMBS it's quite easy, but I just can't wrap my head around how to do it in Cassandra.

Here is an example on what I'm trying to achive in Cassandra on RDMBS:

```
SELECT 
    x.post_id, 
    x.content, 
    x.created_at,
    (
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM post_likes AS p1
            WHERE (p1.user_id = @currentUserId) AND (x.post_id = p1.post_id))
        THEN TRUE::bool ELSE FALSE::bool
    END
) AS "has_current_user_liked_post"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is to create table likes_by_post:

```
CREATE TABLE likes_by_post (
    post_id text,
    user_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY (post_id, user_id)
);
```

This table will allow you to get all users who liked some post:

```
SELECT * FROM likes_by_post WHERE post_id='post_1';
```

check user like for some post:

```
SELECT * FROM likes_by_post WHERE post_id='post_1' AND user_id='user_1';
```

But this approch has the disadvantage - if you expect a lot of user likes per post (millions or billions), this table will have too big partitions it will lead to poor performance and disability to store so many likes per post. Cassandra has a limit 2 billions rows per on partition key.

In this case you can spread information about likes for a single post to several partitions by using compound primary key (this approach usually called Consistent Hashing):

```
CREATE TABLE likes_buckets_by_post (
    post_id text,
    bucket_id int,
    user_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY (( post_id, bucket_id ), user_id)
);
```

Where `bucket_id` is a synthetic field which is responsible to generate different partition keys for different users for the same post.

`bucked_id` should be a some sort of hash based on `user_id` field.
Consistent hashing provides ability to generate some number in specified range based for specified user id. (E.g. Guava java library provides [consistent hashing function](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.html#consistentHash-com.google.common.hash.HashCode-int-))

Before you insert data to the `likes_buckets_by_post` table you need to calculate `bucket_id` by using a consistent hashing function and specified number of buckets:

```
var bucket = consistentHash(user_id, N)
```

Where N is total number of buckets, this number will be depend on your conditions: how many Cassandra nodes you have, how many likes per post do you expect, the greater this number the more partitions will be spreaded used for store.

Please note if you need to request all likes for a post you will have to perform N requests,  but for your case it will require only one request to check single user like for a single post.

```
INSERT INTO likes_buckets_by_post (post_id, bucket_id, user_id) VALUES ('post_1', bucket, 'user_1' );
```

Also before you select data you need to calculate hash with the same parameters as for insert:

```
var bucket = consistentHash(user_id, N)
```

And then you can check a user like for post:

```
SELECT * FROM likes_buckets_by_post WHERE post_id='post_1' AND bucket_id=bucket AND user_id='user_1';
```